# Flutter List View Pagination lazy load the images from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, lazy-loading

i try to implement pagination on my image list from firebase, and i need some help..

// Fetch images from databse for list

```
initSliderImages() async {
var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('galerytab1');
result.snapshots().listen((data) {
  List imgs = [];
  data.docChanges.forEach((change) {
    var imageData = change.doc.data();
    String image = imageData?['url'];
    imgs.add(CachedNetworkImageProvider(image));
  });

  setState(() {
    images = imgs;
  });
});}
```

I create ListView.build and try to fetch data using

```
_scrollListener() {
print(controller.position.extentAfter);
if (controller.position.extentAfter < 13) {
  setState(() {
    images.addAll(List.generate(2, (index) => 'Inserted $index'));
  });
}_scrollListener() {
print(controller.position.extentAfter);
if (controller.position.extentAfter < 13) {
  setState(() {
    images.addAll(List.generate(2, (index) => 'Inserted $index'));
  });
}}
```

@override
void

```
dispose() {
controller.removeListener(_scrollListener);
super.dispose();}
```

but i can't leazy load images that are storaged in this database collection 'galerytab1'

Question: How can i leazy load images from this collection'galerytab1' and display them in listview

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

setState will re-render your build method which causes the list and elements in the list to re-render as well. You can use KeyValue to prevent this from happening.

Also with modern flutter you can use NotificationListener instead of a ScrollController

This sample should give you a rough idea of how it works.
you can run it on [dartpart](https://dartpad.dev/?)

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: PaginationExample(
            key: ValueKey('pagination'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PaginationExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaginationExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<PaginationExample> createState() => PaginationExampleState();
}

class PaginationExampleState extends State<PaginationExample> {
  List<String> urls = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    addUrls();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void addUrls() {
    final List<String> newUrls = List.generate(
      10,
      (_) {
        int random = Random().nextInt(500) + 250; // 250-500
        return 'https://picsum.photos/$random/$random';
      },
    );

    setState(() {
      urls.addAll(newUrls);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
        if (notification.metrics.pixels ==
            notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
          addUrls();
        }

        return true;
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
        key: widget.key,
        itemCount: urls.length,
        itemExtent: 250,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Image.network(
            urls[index],
            key: ValueKey(urls[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when i make code you share, this display random images, but still can't load images from this database collection i made show up..

but when i pull this images in carouse slider this work, but i need in list view